# How to select and edit multiple word with same text in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In visual studio code you can select multiple words with same text using Ctrl+D. What is the equivalent keyboard shortcut on visual studio 2019. I've tried this but it copies a line under it. Here is an example:

```
cout << "hello world";
cout << "hello world";
cout << "hello world";
```

what will I have to do if I want to select all the `cout`s only using keyboard shortcut. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Alt+Shift+;</kbd> to insert a caret at all places where the current word exists.

See [Multi-line and multi-cursor editing](https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing.htm) and [Multi-caret selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019#multi-caret-selection) for more details.

Comment: For me Alt+Shift+. made it! (I use brazilian keyboard layout)